# How to get a serial console on a modern Laptop

Tags: power-management, laptop, serial-console

I would like to observe my Linux system while getting suspended. Reading out the `dmesg` does not work, because my system stops logging until the device resumes. But that's exactly the problem, my device does not return and the log is gone therefore.

There is an option to stop putting consoles into standby, it's called `no_console_suspend`. That's nice, the only problem is: most modern laptops do not have a serial port.

**How can I connect a serial console to those devices?**

I thought about using an USB to serial adapter, unfortunately I guess that wouldn't work because USB is pretty sure suspended.

Any ideas?

Comment: M.2 serial card? You should see something on the console though.

Comment: Not a bad idea, unfortunately my model does only have 1 m.2 slot (sdd)

Comment: Some motherboards have a header (pins to connect to). Perhaps the manufacturer has provided documentation (or can be contacted)? Also, check the BIOS setup for hints? Once found, the console also needs to be activated via Linux command line options during boot. Perhaps this will also work for a USB console.

Answer (score 2):

According to these (old but hopefully valid) docs:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/serial-console.html

a USB serial device can be used as the Linux Serial Console if this is compiled into your kernel. From there:

```
console=device,options
device:         tty0 for the foreground virtual console
                ttyX for any other virtual console
                ttySx for a serial port
                lp0 for the first parallel port
                ttyUSB0 for the first USB serial device
```

Also from there:

> (You can also use a network device as a console. See
> [Documentation/networking/netconsole.rst](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/netconsole.txt) for information on that.)

This may actually be easier if you have an Ethernet port and a second machine.

You can get the current Linux commandline options by

```
cat /proc/cmdline
```

and change them in your GRUB/boot config file, or (easier) during boot for one boot process only.

Comment: the usb bus is deactivated while supend, isn't it?

Comment: @flood I am not sure. I mean we are telling the kernel not to suspend the console. Have you tried using a network console? (I suppose network should then not be configured for anything else,)