# Using netconsole to log netinstall image boot

Tags: linux-kernel, logs, grub2, console, debian-installer

I am trying to log kernel boot messages through the ethernet interface over the local network to another device using `netconsole` following this document: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/netconsole.txt , which I got from [an asnwer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/679993/423679) to another question.

I went through Debian Netinstall until the network was configured, then learnt with `ip address` that the interface is `enp2s0`, the IP address is `192.168.88.17`, and MAC is `d0:50:99:83:4d:25`. I opened the router's interface to check that the IP is kept leased.

I rebooted and modified the kernel's boot parameters from:

```
setparams 'Graphical install'

    set background_color=black
    linux    /install.amd/vmlinuz vga=788 --- quiet
    initrd   /install.amd/gtk/initrd.gz
```

to:

```
setparams 'Graphical install'

    set background_color=black
    linux    /install.amd/vmlinuz vga=788 netconsole=6665@192.168.88.17/enp\
2s0,6666@192.168.88.21/14:f6:d8:b3:99:5d
    initrd   /install.amd/gtk/initrd.gz
```

and hit <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot with that parameters. I immediately copied the `syslog` to a USB drive. I looked through it. The `syslog` and `cat /proc/cmdline` show that the kernel parameters are accepted.

Before booting, on the destination Fedora workstation, I `nc -u -l 6666` to listen on the port, but nothing shows up.

I tried removing `vga=788`, and adding `ignore_loglevel`, but still no message.

There is no `lsof` on the Debian Netinstall.

What should I check to make it right? I am trying to do it with Debian Netinstall first so that I can do it with a similar image that causes trouble.

---

For testing, I tried to invoke `netconsole` on a running Debian Netinstall when the network is configured, but I get the following.

```
~ # insmod netconsole neconsole=@/,@192.168.88.21/
insmod: ERROR: could not load module netconsole: No such file or directory
~ # modeprobe netconsole
modprobe: FATAL: Module netconsole not found in directory /lib/modules/5.10.0-22-amd64
~ # lsmod | grep console
```

It looks like `netconsole` is not included with Debian Netinstall at all. What are my other options to get the kernel boot messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to get the logs from a computer running the Debian installer over `ssh`. For example, this allowed me to get `syslog` from a computer with a USB keyboard working only at the GRUB2 screen but not working after the kernel boot. For this, the `network-console` needs to be preseeded. I opted for preseeding over the local network by adding a URL to the kernel boot parameters directly in GRUB2. Other ways for preseeding are available in the Debian installer documentation. Here is the preseeding configuration file that worked for me:

```
$ cat ~/www/preseed.cfg
# It is necessary to define language settings for ssh to run.
# By example from: https://www.debian.org/releases/bookworm/example-preseed.txt
d-i debian-installer/locale string en_US
d-i keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap select us

# By example from: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/NetworkConsole
d-i anna/choose_modules string network-console
d-i preseed/early_command string anna-install network-console
d-i network-console/password-disabled boolean true
d-i network-console/authorized_keys_url string http://192.168.88.15:8000/id_rsa.pub
```

It is served from a machine on the network:

```
$ hostname --all-ip-addresses
192.168.88.15
$ cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub ~/www/
$ cd ~/www
$ python3 -m http.server
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/) ...
192.168.88.17 - - [24/Jun/2023 01:21:19] "GET /preseed.cfg HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.88.17 - - [24/Jun/2023 01:22:38] "GET /id_rsa.pub HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

This assumes that you have your `ssh` public key saved as `id_rsa.pub`, which is the default for RSA. The last two lines are the target machine accessing the served preseeding file and the public key when configuring `network-console` afterwards. To make the installer automatically configure the network connection with DHCP and load the preseeding file, it should be enough to hit <kbd>e</kbd> and add to Linux kernel parameters `auto=true priority=critical url=` with a URL to the preseeding configuration file. Here is how my boot option looked with that on the Debian Netinstall installer:

```
setparams '... Automated install '

        set background_color=black                                
        linux    /install.amd/vmlinuz auto=true priority=critical url=192.1\
68.88.15:8000/preseed.cfg vga=788 --- quiet
        initrd   /install.amd/initrd.gz
```

Here is another one on Trisquel Netinstall installer:

```
setparams '... Automated install'

        set background_color=black
        linux    /linux auto=true priority=critical url=192.168.88.15:8000/preseed.cfg vga=7\
88 --- quiet
        initrd   /initrd.gz
```

On Debian, `firmware=never` could also be needed to skip asking for installation of non-free firmware for network configuration, but adding it as a kernel boot parameter in a GRUB menu item did not have any effect for me.  It is not needed on Trisquel because Trisquel never offers non-free firmware. If you have the `Help` GRUB2 menu option, it is possible to preseed from the `boot` prompt:

```
boot: /install.amd/vmlinuz vga=788 initrd=/install.amd/gtk/initrd.gz auto=true priority=critical url=192.168.77.15:8000/preseed.cfg ---
```

This line follows examples from: https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/apbs02.en.html#preseed-bootparms-examples

The above assumes that you have one network device on the machine to choose from. Otherwise, the installer may pause to ask you which one to choose.

`ssh` into the machine as user `installer`. You can learn the IP address just from the HTTP server output.

```
$ ssh installer@192.168.88.17
```

The `network-console` does not provide a terminal immediately. Instead, it asks you to choose one of the three options, including whether you want to continue the installation process as usual or to enter the terminal. `scp` and `sftp` do not work in this setup.

```
$ scp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub installer@192.168.88.17:/var/log/syslog ~/
subsystem request failed on channel 0
scp: Connection closed
$ $ sftp -o IdentityFile=~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub installer@192.168.88.17
subsystem request failed on channel 0
Connection closed
$ ssh installer@192.168.88.17 'tar -C /var/log -cf - syslog' > ~/syslog.tar
$ cat ~/syslog.tar
Must be connected to a terminal.
$ mkdir ~/net
$ sshfs installer@192.168.88.17:/ ~/net/ -v
subsystem request failed on channel 0
read: Connection reset by peer
```

<s>I used `nano /var/log/syslog` and copied the log screen by screen.</s>

You can copy the `syslog` with Ncat! Open it for listening on a port on your computer and redirect its output to a file.

```
$ nc -l 6666 > syslog
```

Keep it open and connect to the remote machine.

```
$ ssh installer@192.168.88.17
```

Choose `Start shell`. Send the log to the remote port.

```
~ # cat /var/log/syslog | nc 192.168.88.15 6666
```